# Neural Network with Softmax Output

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, softmax

I am currently learning coding for Multi-Layered Perception. For this MLP I attempted to use logistic sigmoidal for my hidden layers and Softmax for my output with an assumption of two class labels.

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


alpha = 0.1
#Alpha value
alpha = 2*alpha/2
no_iters = 1 #Trying to get 1 iteration to work first.

#Weight matrix to hidden layer (2 input into 2 neuron)
w_h = np.array([ [1.0, 2.0],
              [-2.0, 0.0] ])

#Bias to hidden layer need ( 2 Hidden Layer neurons)
b_h = np.array([3.0, -1])

#Weight matrix to output layer (2 input into 1 neuron)
w_o = np.array([[1.0],
                [1.0]])

#Bias to output layer (Only 1 bias for one output neuron)
b_o = np.array([-2.0])

# X Input Array (No of data rows, No of inputs)
x = np.array([[1.0, 2.0],
              [-2.0, 3.0]])

#Desired Outputs(2 data row = 2 desired output (Rows))
d = np.array([[0.0],
             [1.0]])

#Assume 2 class labels for the 2 data rows
k = np.array([[1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 1.0]])

for iter in range(no_iters):
    #Hidden Layer Functions
    s = np.dot(x,w_h)+ b_h
    z = 1.0/(1 + np.exp(-s))


    #Output Layer Functions (Softmax)
    u = np.dot(z, w_o)+b_o
    u_max = np.max(u, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    p = np.exp(u-u_max)/np.sum(np.exp(u-u_max), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    y = np.argmax(p, axis=1)

    #SoftMax Delta O
    delta_o = k - p

    #Delta for input layer (DZ = differentiation of function)
    dz = z*(1-z)
    delta_h = np.dot(delta_o, np.transpose(w_o))*dz

    #Assign new weight and bias to output layer
    dw = -np.dot(np.transpose(z),delta_o)
    db = -np.sum(delta_o, axis=0)
    w_o = w_o - dw * alpha
    b_o = b_o - db * alpha

    #Assign new weight and bias to hidden layer
    w_h = w_h + alpha*np.dot(np.transpose(x), delta_h)
    b_h = b_h + alpha*np.sum(np.transpose(delta_h), axis=1)

    print(z)
    print(y)
```

When the code is executed there will be issues with matrix dot product for `delta_h = np.dot(delta_o, np.transpose(w_o))*dz`. Due to delta_o being a 2x2 matrix and transpose(w_o) being a  1x2 matrix.

Am I using the wrong formula to approach this problem?

Comment: Could it be that you  should use `w_o` instead of `np.transpose(w_o)`? It will not give an error, but I am not sure that the result is as you are expecting. It looks correct to me, though.

Comment: @norok2 I used 'delta_h = np.dot(delta_o, np.transpose(w_o))*dz' to calculated my delta_h so i definitely transposed my w_o. Unless I declared my w_o wrongly.
Generally I am trying to do a simple classification using a 3-layer feed-forward network with a hidden layer of 2 neurons and an output softmax layer. The desired output is in 'd' and the desired class output in 'k'.

Comment: That is what I meant, and replacing `np.transpose(w_o)` with `w_o` in `delta_h = np.dot(delta_o, np.transpose(w_o))*dz` should fix the code, I tried a few iterations, and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: @norok2 wow really does fixes it. But will it affect the computation? I'm still learning so I'm unsure if changing the formula like that will affect anything. As the formulas I found they transposed w_o when calculating delta_h.

Comment: The transpose is there to make sure that the matrix multiplication works, maybe the formulas you are trying to transcribe have some small inconsistencies with your definitions, e.g. if you want to keep the `delta_h = ...` line as it is, you could as well transpose the definition of `w_o` and the usage of `w_o` in `u = np.dot(z, w_o)+b_o`. It is difficult to get where the exact problem is without knowing your source, but as a general principle, matrix multiplication dimensions must be consistent ;-)

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot multiply two tensors of different sizes. What you can do is you can get the mean of the error vector you are getting and do element-wise modification in the weights. That will not affect the performance and will solve the error I hope.